# How do I delete a bootable partition?

Tags: windows-10, boot-partition

I want to delete a partition with the disk manager of Win 10. I have two OS and I want to delete a partition that has one of them. I have seen a few tutorials that use this kind of programs, but most of them are too old. Do I need any tool to prevent boot problems? why? Thanks, Charles.

Comment: How are the OSes installed, UEFI or Legacy? If UEFI just move the Windows bootloader manager to the first boot order, it doesn't matter. With Legacy, it depends: If using another bootloader for the dual boot then you need to boot the Windows installation media and reinstall the Windows bootloader in MBR.

Comment: As the question is currently written it is a product recommendation request. Change the question to "How do I delete a bootable partition?" and it'll be on-topic.

Comment: @MichaelBay i think is uefi, because it's ubuntu the partition i want to delete and my pc has win 10 for os when i bought it. it´s that right?

Comment: Yes, any factory installed Windows 8 or newer is in UEFI mode. As such, just change the boot order for Ubuntu to Windows and it will boot Windows directly. From there you can do whatever you want.

Comment: @MichaelBay - Windows 7 (64-bit) supports UEFI.  You are not actually required to install Windows 8+ in UEFI mode.  All versions of (x86/x64) Windows support legacy mode.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I know that. Please note the *any factory installed Windows 8 or newer*, not "user installed"... Although Windows 7 can also be installed in UEFI mode, the factory installed ones in UEFI machines were in Legacy. This is an important distinction: One can and should assume UEFI for any factory installed Win8 or newer and Legacy for Win7. User installed OSes can be anything. And I'm well aware there are users installing Windows or other OSes in Legacy for no good reason, to this day.

Comment: Factory is a poor term to use, even by default, is a bad description of the behaviour.  What happens by default, depends on what mode you boot your system in, and even experienced users like myself end up installing Windows while in legacy mode by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Any factory installed Windows 8 or newer is in UEFI mode.

As such, just change the boot order for Ubuntu to Windows bootloader manager and it will boot Windows directly. How to do that varies a lot, please check your users' manual and/or online documentation.

Once set to boot Windows directly you can delete all partitions except the Windows system partition (in use) and the ESP (EFI System Partition).

Other boot entries can be kept because they have no impact on the Windows boot and performance therefore deleting them is optional.